# Why does this C code not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c

Since I am not versed in C, I was trying [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#C) second example of matrix transposition in C, converted simply to JavaScript (code below). It froze the browser.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing the problem? The C program worked fine in ideone.

As Nirk kindly pointed out, the division in the C program was integral rather than floating-point, so the loop was not terminating as it should without using `Math.floor`.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transpose(double *m, int w, int h)
{
  int start, next, i;
  double tmp;

  for (start = 0; start <= w * h - 1; start++) {
    next = start;
    i = 0;
    do {    i++;
      next = (next % h) * w + next / h;
    } while (next > start);
    if (next < start || i == 1) continue;

    tmp = m[next = start];
    do {
      i = (next % h) * w + next / h;
      m[next] = (i == start) ? tmp : m[i];
      next = i;
    } while (next > start);
  }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
function transpose(m, w, h)
{
  var start, next, i,
      tmp

  for (start = 0; start <= w * h - 1; start++) {
    next = start
    i = 0
    do {    i++
      next = (next % h) * w + next / h
    } while (next > start)
    if (next < start || i == 1) continue

    tmp = m[next = start]
    do {
      i = (next % h) * w + next / h
      m[next] = (i == start) ? tmp : m[i]
      next = i
    } while (next > start)
  }
}

function main()
{
  var j
  var m = []
  for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) m[j] = j + 1

  console.log("before transpose:")
  console.log(m)

  transpose(m, 3, 5)

  console.log("\nafter transpose:")
  console.log(m)
}

main()
```

Comment: any debugging statements to tell us at what point it froze or the values suspicious variables had?

Comment: sure - it froze during the `transpose` function...

Comment: so, probably not the source of your problems directly, but you should read up on JS reccomended code style. Its really best to use semicolons, and opening braces (`{`) inline.

Comment: did you debugged your JS code? and how about the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Division is floating point, not integral, so you need `Math.floor(next / h)`

Comment: Some bit-twiddling tricks work as well, for example: `((next / h) | 0)`. There are differences when it comes to negative numbers, but it tends to be a bit faster.

Comment: @TedHopp while it works in this case, the tricks don't work when dealing with numbers larger than `Math.pow(2,32)`.  For example, `((Math.pow(2,33)+1.3)|0) === 1`

Comment: @Nirk - Right. I didn't mean to suggest it as the right thing to do in all cases. But then, OP was porting C code that was using `int` values, so 2^32 is not a realistic concern here. Also, even `Math.floor` is going to be approximate once you get above 2^53 (when you run out of significant bits in a 64-bit IEEE floating point representation). (But it's going to work a lot better than my `|0` hack.)